# Change color Action in Highlight Panel

Tags: css, action, style, lightning-record-page, highlights-panel

I have created an action on a custom object and added it to the Highlights Panel for its record page. Is there a way to change the color of the Action button itself? In an LWC I've been able to do this and wanted to do something similar:

```
<lightning-button variant="success" label="Create" title="Create" onclick={show} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

I've searched extensively and have not come across any solutions regarding this so I'm expecting a "no, you can't do that". Hoping to be proven wrong though